# Template matching two (seemingly) unrelated types

Tags: c++, templates, enums, sfinae

I have a scoped enum:

```
enum class E
{ A, B, C };
```

Now I want to have a function, which accepts a value of that scoped int OR an `int` itself.

It should be something like:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, enum E **OR** int>::value, int> = 0 >
void foo(T value);
```

But I don't know how to deal with the concept of OR in C++ templates. I know `std::is_convertible`, however I don't even know, if I could use it here, because you can only `static_cast` scoped `enum`s to int.

But anyway I don't want to accept any type that is convertible to `int` but only types of that single enum or int.

Comment: use is_same twice and perform a logical or on the value.

Comment: Typically you use an enum because those are the only acceptable values for your function. Can you just require an enum and let the caller figure out what their int means to them in terms of the enum?

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't know you could do that, I already searched if there was something like `std::or`. I thought so, because `std::is_same` isn't the same as `==` too.

Comment: @GManNickG Think of a function, which creates a window. Sometimes you want them to have a certain size, sometimes you want them to be maximized. I would use an enum value for `maximized` and let the callee figure out, what size that actually means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overload seems the simplest:

```
void foo(int value);
void foo(E value) { foo(static_cast<int>(value); } // Or specific code
template <typename T> void foo(T) = delete; // To forbid type convertible to int
```

else you can use SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>::value || std::is_same<E, T>::value>
foo(T value);
```

Comment: I agree that overload usually seems the simplest, but the more you get used them, the more you learn to appreaciate only having to deal with one function, instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

Because `std::is_same<...>::value` is a boolean, you can simply use `||` operator with 2 `std::is_same<...>::value` :

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, enum E>::value || std::is_same<T, int>::value, int> = 0 >
void foo(T value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_same` instantiations define a `constexpr` implicit `bool` conversion, so you can instantiate them and perform logical OR with `||`. In C++17, you will also be able to use [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) to similar effect, although this will likely compile slower for only two type traits. Example of both:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class E
{ A, B, C };

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<T, E>{} || std::is_same<T, int>{},
int> = 0>
void foo(T){
}

//in C++17, you can also do this:
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, E>, std::is_same<T, int>>{},
int> = 0>
void bar(T){
}


int main() {
    foo(E::A);
    foo(0);
    //foo('A'); fails

    bar(E::A);
    bar(0);
    //bar('A'); fails
    return 0;
}
```

`std::disjunction` is the logical OR template you were wondering about (although I recommend using `||` with `std::is_same` for your case). Interestingly, `std::disjunction` even performs logical short-circuiting of template instantiations, just like the humble old `||` operator does in a runtime context. I believe recent versions of libc++ are already shipping with `std::disjunction`. If your `<type_traits>` implementation doesn't have it yet, the example implementation at cppreference works just fine for me. If you get the chance, you should see how it works. It's rather clever!